# rails http request with file on body

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, ssl, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using trello api to attach an image to a card. the documentation says

```
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'

url = URI("https://api.trello.com/1/cards/id/attachments")

http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url)

response = http.request(request)
puts response.read_body
```

After putting my key and my token, I tried to upload a file and the binary data goes in the url itself, not only it seems too ugly but it also doesn't work because the request is really too long. I've tried using multipart and rest client gems from in my code to upload and attach a file to a trello card but everytime I get errors like bad request or SSL errors, can anyone please give me a piece of code that really works? thanks
actually I am sending the image data via AJAX (I'm generating it from a charjs view), so the data sent is binary, it would be better if the solution upload an image from binary data.

Answer (score 0):

Their documentation does indeed encourage you to add the whole encoded file object into the URL, which I also find ugly. I wonder if it will work to add it into the POST body instead? Try this:

```
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url)
request.set_form_data({file: put_encoded_file_contents_here})
```

Comment: I was able to write in the body but I always get an empty attachment. Even with your example.